# Identify change in job code from a mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I am working with a very large table in MySQL containing employee information collected over the last four years.  I want to know if someone's job code changed between that time, and if so, push their data into an array for json encoding in php.

An example of the data looks like this:

```
Year    Emp ID    Job Code
2015     1234         X908
2014     1234         X908
2013     1234         X908
**2015     5421         Y444**
2014     5421         Z900
2013     5421         Z900
```

For employee 1234 there has been no job change between 2013-2015; I would however like to catch employee 5421 whose job code changed between 2014 and 2015.

So far, I have written a script in PHP without good results.

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT year, emp_id, job_code from big_table ");

$rows = array();

while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

 if ($r['emp_id'] == $r['emp_id'] and $r['job_code'] != $r['job_code']) {

    $rows[] = $r;

 } 

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You will probably need to organize your $rows array so that you are able to check for duplicate employees, then if a duplicate is found check the job_code and perform desired actions from there for each employee.

Comment: Select distinct emp_id as employees, foreach employees as employee select distinct job_code, count job_code  if greater than 1 the job changed whack em into arry

Answer (score 2):

You can get the required data in the SQL query without having to pull all user records into PHP. This will be significantly more efficient than processing the data in PHP.

You can get the job code count for each user:

```
SELECT emp_id, COUNT(DISTINCT job_code) AS diffjobs FROM big_table GROUP BY emp_id
```

Then you can conditionally get users with more than 1 distinct job code by wrapping it in a subquery:

```
SELECT emp_id, diffjobs FROM 
    (SELECT emp_id, COUNT(DISTINCT job_code) AS diffjobs FROM big_table GROUP BY emp_id) d
    WHERE diffjobs > 1
```

Comment: Thank you Tristan, I will try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

This loop should work:

```
$rows = array();
$jobChanges = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  if (!isset($rows[$r['emp_id']])){
    $rows[$r['emp_id']] = $r;
  } elseif ($rows[$r['emp_id']]['job_code'] != $r['job_code']) {
    // Handle differing job_code...
    if (!isset($jobChanges[$r['emp_id'])) {
      $jobChanges[$r[emp_id]] = array();
    }
    // Keep track of all differing job codes per emp_id
    // I am not going to go any further than that...
    $jobChanges[$r[emp_id]][] = $r;
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (!isset($row[$r['emp_id']])){ $rows[$r['emp_id']] = $r; }` will add a row for every `emp_id`. The OP only wants to add a row it there is a change in `job_code` for the `emp_id`.

Comment: Also, where is `$row` coming from -> `$row[$r['emp_id']]`

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! I will give this approach a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired employees whose job has changed in between years using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause, like this:

```
$query  = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT emp_id from big_table GROUP BY emp_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT job_code) > 1");

$rows = array();
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $rows[] = $r;
} 

echo json_encode($rows);
```

**Caution:** Don't mix `mysqli` and `mysql` database extensions in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a `JOIN` query in MySQL, so that you only return the rows that have changed from the previous year -

```
SELECT 
    a.year, a.emp_id, a.job_code, 
    b.year prev_year, b.job_code prev_job_code
FROM big_table a
JOIN big_table b
ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id
AND b.year = a.year-1
WHERE a.job_code != b.job_code
```

see this SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95e680/10

so your code could be simplified to -

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT a.year, a.emp_id, a.job_code, b.year prev_year, b.job_code prev_job_code FROM big_table a JOIN big_table b ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id AND b.year = a.year-1 WHERE a.job_code != b.job_code ");

$rows = array();

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $rows[] = $r;

 } 

echo json_encode($rows);
```

note - you had `mysqli_query()`, but `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, so I updated to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

---

If you still wanted to do this in php, you need to save the last row value to a temporary array, and then check if the `job_code` has changed.

it would look something like this -

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT year, emp_id, job_code from big_table ORDER BY emp_id, year");

$temp = array();    
$rows = array();

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

 if(!isset($temp[$r['emp_id']]){

     $temp[$r['emp_id']] = $r; // add this row to the temp array

 }
 else {

     if ($r['job_code'] != $temp[$r['emp_id']]['job_code']) {

        // add the previous values for comparison
        $r['prev_year'] = $temp[$r['emp_id']]['year'];
        $r['prev_job_code'] = $temp[$r['emp_id']]['job_code'];

        // add this row
        $rows[] = $r; // add this row

        // replace the last temp array with this array
        $temp[$r['emp_id']] = $r;

     }

 } 

echo json_encode($rows);
```

note - I changed the query by adding an `ORDER BY` -> `ORDER BY emp_id, year`

Comment: Wow, the SQL works great!  Thanks Sean.  Not sure where how the mysqli crept in so thanks for the catch.  My table is over 200k records; when I run a query like this one, I have to limit the rows returned to about 50k or else my server throws a 500 error.  Also, even on a 50k query, the query takes over 10 seconds.  I did index emp_id but that had no effect.  Any ideas on how to run a fast query on all 200+k records?  Thanks!!

Comment: Ah, never mind, I figured it out - did not set the index correctly on emp_id